# How to add an additional cell in gridview showing total number of rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to put the **total number of rows in a cell at the bottom of an asp.net gridview**. I can do so far is showing it outside the gridview, but the requirement is to show it at the bottom of the gridview itself. How to achieve that?

Comment: Make your Question Understandable

Comment: You could use gridview footer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx (very old, may still work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to define variable for record count as RowNumber and define lable to display number of row at footer and refer below code, it may help you.

```
private int RowNumber=0; // Define at the top
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {

      RowNumber += 1;
   }
    // you need to add one label at Footer section
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {
      Label lblTotalRow = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalRow");
      lblTotalRow.Text = RowNumber.ToString();
   }
}
```